# How to automate Quay.io login in a shell script?

Tags: bash, docker

I've got a shell script that I use to configure my Ubuntu instance upon instantiation. One of the things I need to do is login to my `Quay.io` account so I can pull docker images from my private registry. Kinda like so:

**Instance-Config.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker login quay.io -u 'myUserName' -p 'myPassword' -e 'me@mydomain.com'

docker run quay.io/myUserName/myContainerName
```

The above script works just fine when logging in to `Dockerhub`, but when I try to use it to login to `Quay.io` it produces prompts for the various arguments (-u, -p, -e) when it should automatically fill those from the arguments provided in the command.

How do I go about automating login for `Quay.io`?

---

I should note that I've already tried logging in, copying the contents of the `~/.dockercfg` file and then trying to `echo` the resulting string into a new `.dockercfg` file in the `Instance-Init.sh` script but there must be a machine id or something in the auth token that's produced and placed in the `.dockercfg` file so the resulting login from one machine cannot be used on a new instance (which is probably a good thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doi. You need to put the `host` argument at the *end*, like [illustrated in their docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#login):

```
#!/bin/bash

docker login -u 'myUserName' -p 'myPassword' -e 'me@mydomain.com' quay.io

docker run quay.io/myUserName/myContainerName
```

Hopefully that'll help someone else save some time.